# Is mass an inherent property?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Suppose I have an electronic weighing machine placed in a uniform gravitational field. Now I put a mass above it and register the reading. Now I give the system (mass + machine) an impulse so that it travels at $0.99c$. Will the reading on the scales change and why?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking. You can only weigh a mass if it's stationary with respect to the scales, and you'll only get an accurate reading if the scales are stationary wrt the Earth. If some superrocket accelerated the mass, the scales and the whole Earth to 0.99c, so they all stayed stationary wrt each other, then the reading on the scales wouldn't change.

Comment: why is it necessary?? if i have a friction less plate above the weighing machine and i shoot the mass then will the readings change or not?? also what do you mean by " accurate reading if the scales are stationary wrt the Earth"?

Comment: If you drop the scales and mass down a mine shaft the scales will show zero weight (until they hit the bottom! :-) That's what I mean by the scales must be stationary wrt the Earth.

Comment: I think the OP means that given a uniform gravitational field, e.g. $U(x,y,z)=\text{const}(x,y)$, we weigh the body against $z$ coordinate, and then accelerate it to $0.99c$ in $xy$ plane and then compare the scale's reading.

Comment: Any form of scales I know measure inertial forces. When you weight something on the Earth's surface you are accelerating it away from the geodesic it would normally trace. The only way I can think of to do what you suggest is to take the scales away, let the mass speed pass the Earth and see how much the Earth moves and whether this depends on the speed. Actually that's an interesting question, and I'd need to sit down and think about it.

Comment: all i want to ask is that, is mass an inherent property?? for example if i take a charged body and measure its charge while moving, through inertial effect(like measuring force acting on it) it will be same as when it was in rest (hence charge is a fundamental property). so does the inertial mass (not rest mass) have similar property??

Answer (score 1):

In short the answer is no - the measurement of mass depends on your frame. Here's a (somewhat lengthy) explanation.

First let's be clear about the setup. We'll make the following assumptions

- an object $A$ is at rest in the frame of an observer $O$
- $O$ measures a uniform gravitational field in some direction of strength $g$

Now $O$ can measure the mass of the object $A$ in two ways namely

- put $A$ on a set of scales at rest and determine the weight then divide by the field strength $g$
- apply a force to $A$ and measure its acceleration then find the mass by $F = ma$

These two methods give the same answer in all experiments ever done, and determine the **rest mass** of $A$.

Now suppose that relative to a second observer $O'$ the whole setup containing $O$ and $A$ is moving at $0.99c$. This doesn't affect what $O$ himself measures, since there's no physical meaning in relative inertial motion according to special relativity.

But we really want to know $O'$ would measure. So suppose $O'$ had his own set of scales which he put under $A$ at the instant he passed $O$.

- first note that $O'$ would measure the **same** field strength $g$ as $O$ because the field is uniform and the laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames
- $O'$ would get a **different** weight reading on his scales and therefore conclude that $A$ had a different mass to that measured by $O$

But why should $O$ get a different mass? We can do a simple "proof" if you accept Einstein's axiom

$$E = mc^2$$

where $E$ is the total energy of $A$ in the frame of $O'$ and $m$ is the mass measured by $O'$. The argument goes like this.

- The mass measured by $O'$ is thus $m = E/c^2$
- From the perspective of $O'$ $A$ is moving very fast so has more kinetic energy that it seems to $O$
- Hence the energy measured by $O'$ is larger than that measured by $O$
- So $O'$ measures a larger mass than $O$

The mass measured by $O'$ is called the **relativistic mass**.

In reality nobody really works with the relativistic mass because people can't agree on it. Everyone just uses the **rest mass** because it's the same for all observers **by definition**! Indeed if $O'$ took $A$ with him at $0.99c$ and weighed it he'd get the same answer as $O$ got before.

A caveat: things aren't so simple when you think about general relativity. It's difficult to precisely define local rest mass for particles, because the fundamental conserved quantity is the **density** of energy and momentum through spacetime. As a result $O$ and $O'$ might even disagree about the **rest mass** of $A$.

The heuristic reasoning is as follows. In GR there is a constant exchange of energy and momentum through the universe. The net rate of this exchange depends on your frame of reference. So changing frames changes your observations about mass in the universe.

*References*

[An experiment to measure relativistic mass](http://physics.dickinson.edu/~dept_web/activities/papers/relativity.pdf)

[Matt Strassler on Rest Mass](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/)

[Harvey Reall on Energy in GR (see sec 5.2)](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/lecturenotes_2012.pdf)

Comment: i have the problem with the concept that in E=m(c^2), m is the mass that O' will measure. i can't get why fundamentally mass should change. as whatever action-reaction forces act on mass, they do in vertical direction.why motion in horizontal direction should effect the mass measured by above setup. also what do you mean by saying that conserved quantity is energy density? we have till now learned that energy is conserved.

Comment: Okay. Would you accept that special relativity modifies  our notion of velocity (and therefore momentum)? If so, good. If not, you just have to accept that's the way the universe works! Having accepted this, it's a short step to see how exactly the momentum should change - see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43969/relativistic-momentum/43982#43982) answer.

Comment: Alternatively if you are willing to accept that mass and energy are the same thing (which they are in special relativity) the "extra" mass comes from the "extra" kinetic energy of the particle in the frame of $O'$.

Comment: Finally the fact that energy density is conserved in GR  rather than local energy is best viewed as a mathematical feature of the theory. It's analogous to the conserved currents you get in classical field theory. If you want more details, look at the lecture notes I attached to the answer.

Comment: my doubt arise as in the book Spacetime physics by wheeler, it says that momentum is not m*v where m is the relativistic mass. it is m*(dx/dt) where t is the proper time and m is the mass which is same in all frames. so as t is proper time, that is why the factor of gamma comes in. hence he argues that reativistic mass doesn't have any physical significance

Comment: Wheeler says that the $4$-momentum is $m_0 \times dx/d\tau$ where $\tau$ is proper time for the object $A$. In the $O'$ frame time will tick differently, say his proper time is $\tau'$. If $O'$ were to measure the velocity of $A$ he'd get a result $dx/d\tau'$. Now from time dilation we know that $\tau' = \gamma\tau$. This tells us that $O'$ measures the momentum of $A$ to be $m_0 \times \gamma \times dx/d\tau'$. Since the final factor is a genuine measurement made by $O'$ we conclude that $O'$ deduces that the relativistic mass of $A$ is $m_0 \gamma = m$.

Comment: I would have to disagree slightly with the Wheeler book. I think that relativistic mass is **physical** in the sense that you can measure it. It's just not a very **useful** quantity, because it differs between frames. This is analogous to saying that coordinate time in a particular frame is **physical** in the sense that the observer in that frame experiences it. But it's not very **useful** because time dilation means different observers don't agree on coordinate time. That's why we normally use rest mass and proper time in physics, especially when we're doing mathematical calculations.